# Is there water after Sultan's Zoo?

Tags: prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time

I'm playing Prince of Persia: Sands of Time.  After "Atop a Bird's Cage", which itself follows the Sultan's Zoo, I have to do a speed run against traps.  But the last water I've found was at the bottom of the bird's cage in the Sultan's Zoo.

By the time I climb up the cage, jump across to the save point, open the door, and fight my way past scarabs, I have barely any life left.  So I just keep dying and dying on the trap run.

Is there a source of water I have overlooked?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no water source to regain your health. However, the sequence you speak of only involves four different types of trap, and with the right strategy it is quite easy to pass it without taking *any* damage. In fact, if I remember correctly, the traps you face during the run are all one-hit kills, so having more health will not be as much of an advantage.

## The Run

It has been a long time since I've played this title, so I found [a video of someone completing that section](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAuOw9u6ixk) to remind me. It is worth noting that the more sand tank you have at your disposal, the better, as you can obviously reverse time if you fail a trap.

#### Spinning Blades

[image: Spinning Blade Trap]

Blades that perform 180 degree swings in set increments. These ones are particularly nasty, as they have floor spikes along one of the sides.

First of all, you want to move around the **left** side of the first blade, the **right** side of the second, and the **left** side of the third. This will avoid the floor spikes. Just move to the right side, and hug the wall.

Secondly, you want to listen for the sound of the swing. All three traps swing together, and make a distinct sound, as they do. If you time a roll just before the sound effect, you will most likely roll through the trap, and miss the blade completely.

### Spiked Pit

[image: Spiked Pit Trap]

Simply jump over the first pit you come across, as you will have ample room. The second pit requires a wall run, which brings us to the next trap..

### Wall Saws

[image: Wall Saw Trap]

The blades that move up and down the wall run can be annoying, but if you wait for them to rise a little higher then the Prince, you will have plenty of time to wall run across, under them.

### Floor Spikes

[image: Floor Spike Trap]

The last trap you will have to face, at least properly, is the floor spike panels you moved around during the rotating blades phase. At this point, you should have enough time to simply walk over the panels. Providing you walk, the spikes will not trigger.

### The Gate

You should be able to get to the gate with ample time. Just remember that you can roll under it, if it has already closed too far to allow you to walk through it.

Comment: Very nice answer !

Comment: The spiked pit is a one-hit kill. The spinning blades and floor spikes take some of your health, but if you have enough they are not one-hit kills. The wall saws technically aren't one-hit kills, either, but are often placed over long drops or spiked pits, which means that they essentially are.